# Problems with click listener for header in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

So, I have a header view defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/purchase_menu_header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/purchase_options_label"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inflated as follows:

`View header = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.purchase_menu_header, options, false);
options.addHeaderView(header);`

I have an click listener for items in the options ListView:

```
options.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Offer offer = (Offer) options.getItemAtPosition(position);
                initiatePurchase(offer.getStoreProduct());
            }
        });
```

And a click listener for the header view itself:

```
header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                baseLayout.removeView(background);
                baseLayout.removeView(overlay);
            }
        });
```

My problem is that the header only registers clicks on the text portion of the header. The desired behaviour is to have the entire header clickable. I have tried solutions such as using setOnItemClickListener with a getItemAtPosition(0), but this returns null. Have also tried to expand the text view in the header with MATCH_PARENT, but no luck there.

Comment: Have you tried removing the LinearLayout, i.e. have your layout file contain just the TextView? You can then adjust gravity and/or padding for the TextView to get text where you want it.

Comment: I will be adding an image to the header as well, so I don't think that solution will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your LinearLayout clickable using the [android:clickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable) attribute.

Comment: Try making the header view clickable programmatically, via setClickable (true).

Comment: Strangely enough, the programmatically way actually worked. For the record, an alternate solution was to create a blank view (I used an ImageView) inside the header view with `match_parent` width/height. Thanks Cyber Sam!

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, many attributes of the outermost layout view often tend to be ignored, I've learned through experience.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that the header only registers clicks on the text
>   portion of the header.

Cause your header is just the `TextView` with `wrap_content` as width and height. Hence you are applying `clicklistener` to `TextView` with restricted clickable area.

> Solution:

1. use `match_parent` as width for `TextView`. Or
2. use the `LinearLayout` that contains the `TextView` in it, as the header and make that clikable.

Hope it helps you.